# Show that $a_n<\sqrt{2}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: calculus

We define $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(a_n+\dfrac{2}{a_n}\right)$.

I want to prove that $a_n$ converges. But first I'd like to show that $a_n<\sqrt{2}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I try to use induction. For a fixed $n$, I suppose that $a_n<\sqrt{2}$.

Any hint to prove that $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(a_n+\dfrac{2}{a_n}\right)<\sqrt{2}$?

Thanks.

Comment: Your assumption that $a_n<\sqrt{2}$ doesn't hold for n>1.

Comment: In fact it true that $a_n \geq \sqrt{2}$ for all $n > 1$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas, even for $n=1$?

Comment: @BarryCipra, edited.

Comment: @AntonioVargas, your edit appeared instantaneously (for me) with my comment.  I would delete my comment, but for some reason the edit and delete options on comments haven't been available to me lately.  (I'm also no longer seeing timestamps on comments.)  I don't know why this is.

Comment: @BarryCipra, that's strange.  You may get some help if you post on meta with some screenshots to illustrate.

Comment: You're right. Then, how would you prove that $a_n$ converges?

Comment: Assume that $\displaystyle a_n$ converges, i.e $\displaystyle \exists L \in \mathbb{R} \ s.t \ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$. What next? Can you find L?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$ 2 a_n a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + 2, $$
from which it follows that:
$$ a_{n+1}^2-2 = (a_{n+1}-a_n)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{a_n}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{a_n^2-2}{2a_n}\right)^2 > 0, $$
so $a_n > \sqrt{2}$ for every $n > 1$. If we set $b_n = a_{n+1}^2-2$, we have $b_1=\frac{1}{4},b_n>0$ and:
$$ b_n = \frac{b_{n-1}^2}{4a_n^2} = \frac{b_{n-1}^2}{4(b_{n-1}+2)} \leq \frac{b_{n-1}^2}{8}, $$
from which it follows that the sequence $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ decreases very fast towards zero. For instance, $b_1=\frac{1}{4}$ and the last inequality imply, by induction:
$$ b_n \leq \frac{1}{2^{5\cdot 2^{n-1}-3}}.$$