# How to show that the limit of this sequence exists?

Tags: calculus

We define $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\dfrac 12\left(a_n+\dfrac{2}{a_n}\right)$.

I'd like to show that this sequence converges (and $a_n\to\sqrt{2}$). So, I wanted to prove that $a_n$ is monotonic and bounded. I thought that $a_n<\sqrt{2}$, but I was wrong. Maybe this sequence isn't even monotonic.

What do you think?

I already know that if the limit exists, say $l$, then $l=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(l+\dfrac{2}{l}\right)$. But we still need to prove that $a_n$ converges.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own question. In the latter, someone already proved convergence for you: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/976611/136641.

Comment: There is something you might try:
If a sequence of real numbers is bounded and have only one limit point, then it converges towards this limit point. Proving that uses bolzano weirstrauss theorem, maybe it'll help you

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question you yourself wrote. Do not do that!

Answer (score 1):

From a purely algebraic point of view, consider the Newton iteration scheme for $f(x)=x^2-2$; it write $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ that is to say here $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\Big(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}\Big)$$ The second derivative of the function is $2$ and, as well known for Newton method, if you start at a point such that $f(x_0) f''(x_0)>0$, the process will converge without any overshoot of the solution. In your case, starting from $1$,$f(1)<0$ then leads to an overshoot and the first iterate is $\frac{3}{2}$. But, for this new point, $f(\frac{3}{2})=\frac{1}{4} >0$; from here, the convergence is ensured.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can be noted is that by $A.M.-G.M.$ inequality,
$$a_{n+1}=\frac {a_n}2+\frac 1{a_n} \ge 2\sqrt{\frac {a_n}2*\frac 1{a_n}} \ge \frac 2{\sqrt{2}} \ge \sqrt{2}$$
This holds for $n \gt 1$. Now its easy to see that $a_{n+1} \lt a_n$ for $a_n \gt \sqrt{2}$. 
Hence $$\lim_{x\to \infty} a_n \to \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: first of all it is to prove that $a_n>0$ for all $n$ is hold

Comment: yeah..that's right but since $a_1=1$ and there is no negative sign in the formula of $a_{n+1}$ from $a_n$...it is pretty obvious that all $a_i$s are positive..